# Exponential solution to ODE if and only if linear?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm wondering if some form of the following statement is true. Suppose I'm given a separable ODE of the form
$$y'(t) = g(y(t))$$
for some sufficiently smooth $g$ and initial condition $y(t_0)=y_0$. Is it true that this ODE has a solution of the (exponential) form
$$y(t) = k_0 + k_1\exp(k_2t)$$
if and only if $g$ is affine (i.e. $g(x) = ax+b$ for constants $a,b$). One direction (the fact that affine $g$ implies exponential solution) is true just by solving the ODE with affine $g$, but I'm wondering if the converse holds? In particular, if we try to solve the ODE by the standard method, we get the equation
$$\int_{y(t_0)}^y \frac1{g(y)} = t$$
and in a sense the anti-derivative will only take some $\log$ form when $g$ is linear. Sorry if this is not too precise but I thought some form of this statement would be true (perhaps given some extra conditions on $g$).

Comment: So start with $y=k_0+k_1\exp(k_2 t)$ and look at what you are demanding on $g$.

Comment: I see, once you write it that way this implies that $g$ is affine with the coefficients given by the $k$'s, thanks!

Comment: I suggest you write up your solution as an answer and approve it so that future users may search and reference it.

Comment: The trivial direction is not clear to me. If $g(x)=1$ (that is $a=0$, $b =1$) the solution is of the form $y(t)=c+t$, hence not of the form you want.